# How to set focus on a field that isn't in view?

Tags: angular

How i can take my focus to invalid field after click on submit if my form is as big that i need to scroll, it should go to specific field wherever it may be i need not to scroll my page in search of relevant invalid field.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which element in the form is invalid you can give it focus by:

```
$("#element").focus();
```

To scroll it into view use the following which uses the Javascript DOM element.  This will not have smooth scrolling howveer.:

```
$("#element").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I've been told that you don't want to use jQuery in an Angular app because they don't play nice together.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost definitely the wrong answer because it is likely not the Angular way of doing things, but why not just use raw javascript?

The trick however, is getting at the element.  This is how i've done it in the past:

In the template, every element would need a reference variable like so:

```
<input #myRef ...  />
```

Then in the component you need to use a view child:

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

...

export class MyClass {
    @ViewChild('myRef') input: ElementRef;

    myFocusFunction() {
        this.input.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
```

This is how you would focus on the element, but you could also use this to then determine the x or y offset of the element and then scroll to the proper position on the page.

So something along the lines of this:

```
let rect = this.input.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

window.scrollTo(rect.top, 0);
```